# How to detect when laptop power cable has been disconnected?

Tags: c#, .net

For the umpteenth time my laptop just shut down in the middle of my game because my power cable had disconnected without me noticing it.

Now I want to write a little C# program that detects when my power cable disconnects and then emits a nice long System beep. What API could I use for that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should be trivial to implement using the [SystemInformation.PowerStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.powerstatus.aspx) property. And even though that lives in Windows.Forms, it should be perfectly usable from a system service.

For a solution that also works on the Compact Framework, see [HOWTO: Get the Device Power Status](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457088.aspx)

Comment: The link is not working now, please update if possible.

Comment: Is there anyway to find the information from windows command line?

Answer (score 11):

[SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.powermodechanged.aspx). You will need to use either GetSystemPowerStatus (see link in one of the answers) or SystemInformation.PowerStatus (link is in another answer) in the handler to check what happened.

Comment: your ans was just what I needed thanx :)

Comment: This is awesome and should be the accepted answer. The question was to detect when it happens, not monitor it constantly until it does. Well done. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This will probably get closed as not-programming-related, but you may want to check your BIOS setttings.

My Lenovo laptop does exactly what you're suggesting natively. There is a setting in my BIOS for beeping on power status change.

Comment: Notice how he cleverly worded it as a programming question. I can imagine other circumstances where a program would want to know if it was running on battery power, so it's a good question to have in the database.

Answer (score 2):

To continue BQ's answer, there are power settings in Windows that can be changed when the power cord is removed. Since I sometimes work with it removed I didn't change the power settings on my machine, but when the battery approaches 15% the screen brightness is set to the lowest level, making it possible to work (and easily changeable with Fn-Home key) but very noticeable so that I plug the cable back in time.

Answer (score 2):

Here, is a little solution:
using C# windows form application,

```
PowerStatus powerStatus = SystemInformation.PowerStatus;

if (powerStatus.PowerLineStatus == PowerLineStatus.Online)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Running On Power", Convert.ToString(powerStatus.BatteryLifePercent * 100) + "%");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Running On Battery", Convert.ToString(powerStatus.BatteryLifePercent * 100) + "%");
}
```

Hope, you got the idea, now you can use it in any way,...........

Answer (score 1):

For Windows and .NET 6+, I wrote a wrapper around the win32 [System Power Status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/system-power-status) APIs. My code not only wraps `GetSystemPowerStatus` in a convenient way, but also lets you subscribe to OS events to be notified when:

- **The power source changes**
- Battery percentage changes
- Battery saver turns on/off
- Current monitor's display state changes
- The lid opens/closes
- The power scheme changes
- The primary monitor turns on/off
- The session display's state changes
- The system enters/leaves "away mode"
- The system is not idle
- The user is/isn't active

https://www.nuget.org/packages/PowerStatus

Answer (score 0):

This may very much depend on your exact operating system.
Here are some calls for windows XP, I am sure you can find the Vista equivalents:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms704147(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Can't think of anything directly accessible via the .NET framework, but I do know that Intel has the Mobile Platform SDK with .NET libraries that should provide this information to you. It's possible AMD has an equivilent somewhere.

[Intel Mobile Platform SDK](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/making-applications-aware-of-their-mobile-contexts-using-the-intel-mobile-platform-sdk)