# How to detect when the laptop is running on batteries in .NET?

Tags: .net, mode

How to detect when the laptop is running on batteries (or AC) in .NET?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect when laptop power cable has been disconnected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347862/how-to-detect-when-laptop-power-cable-has-been-disconnected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to detect when laptop power cable has been disconnected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347862/how-to-detect-when-laptop-power-cable-has-been-disconnected)

Answer (score 0):

For Vista and up, you can use [WindowsAPICodecPack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) (PowerManager.PowerSourceChanged)