# Win32 Event Handlng - Checking if charger is plugged in

Tags: c++, winapi, event-handling

I'm trying to do my first Windows app with C++ and I'm really struggling with how to implement event handlers. I'm reading through the Win32 documentation, but it's really sparse on examples. Unfortunately,  I can't seem to find much on YouTube or other written sources for much beyond making the first window.

The basic idea of my app is to have it change the refresh rate of the display based on whether or not the charger for a laptop is plugged in. This is mostly for personal use since my laptop supports 144Hz and 60Hz, and I want to take advantage of the higher rate when  plugged in, but get the benefits of better battery life when unplugged (without the tedium of going through the display settings every time I plug in/unplug).

My background is primarily in Android development, but this all seems a bit more daunting than that. I've come across these links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.powermodechanged?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.powermodechangedeventhandler?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

[How to detect when laptop power cable has been disconnected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347862/how-to-detect-when-laptop-power-cable-has-been-disconnected)

These seem to be what I'm looking for, but I haven't the slightest idea of how to actually put this together in the context of my app, though it seems like I might really want to use PowerModeChangedEventHandler. Here's what I've gotten so far (a lot of copy/paste work with modifications):

```
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

static char *title = TEXT("Refresh Changer");

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    DEVMODE dm;
    ZeroMemory(&dm, sizeof(dm));
    dm.dmSize = sizeof(dm);

    MSG  msg;
    WNDCLASS wc = {0};
    wc.lpszClassName = TEXT("autoRefresh");
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);


    RegisterClass(&wc);
    CreateWindow(wc.lpszClassName, title, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW|WS_VISIBLE, 860, 540, 350, 150, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);  

    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

    switch(msg) {
        case WM_CREATE: {
            CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("Enable automatic refresh rate changer"), WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD|BS_CHECKBOX, 20, 20, 300, 35, hwnd, (HMENU) 1, ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance, NULL);
            CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 1, BST_CHECKED);
            break;
        }

        case WM_COMMAND: {
            BOOL checked = IsDlgButtonChecked(hwnd, 1);
            if (checked) {
                //if/else blocks to check charger status and current refresh rate, then change accordingly
            } else {
                CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 1, BST_CHECKED);
                SetWindowText(hwnd, title);
            }
            break;
        }

        case WM_DESTROY: {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        }

    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

This is about all I need for the GUI aspect, at least for the first version. But I just really feel lost about registering for power events/checking and going from there.

Comment: You can use `RegisterPowerSettingNotification` to get notifications sent to your window in the form of `WM_POWERBROADCAST` messages.

Comment: Yeah I saw that, it's one of the links I listed in my post, but I don't know how to implement that. The documentation around it is super brief and doesn't really list arguments or give examples of how to do it. Sorry, I'm trying to do my own research, but it there just doesn't seem to be much out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have a window handle `hWnd`, call the `RegisterPowerSettingNotification` function.

```cpp
RegisterPowerSettingNotification(hWnd, &GUID_ACDC_POWER_SOURCE, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);
```

In your window procedure, look for `WM_POWERBROADCAST` messages and check `wParam` for the power management event.

```cpp
switch (message)
{
  case WM_POWERBROADCAST:
    if (wParam == PBT_APMPOWERSTATUSCHANGE)
    {
      SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS status;
      if (GetSystemPowerStatus(&status))
      {
         // Look at the status structure for power information
      }
    }
    else if (wParam == PBT_POWERSETTINGCHANGE)
    {
      POWERBROADCAST_SETTING *pSetting = (POWERBROADCAST_SETTING *)lParam;
      // Look at the structure for power information
    }
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Registering for Power Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/registering-for-power-events):

> An application receives a WM_POWERBROADCAST message with a wParam of
> PBT_POWERSETTINGCHANGE and an lParam that points to a
> POWERBROADCAST_SETTING structure.

[Power Setting GUIDs:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/power-setting-guids)

> Power setting GUIDs are defined in WinNT.h.
>
> GUID_ACDC_POWER_SOURCE
>
> 5D3E9A59-E9D5-4B00-A6BD-FF34FF516548
>
> The system power source has changed. The Data member is a DWORD with
> values from the SYSTEM_POWER_CONDITION enumeration that indicates the
> current power source.
>
> PoAc (0) - The computer is powered by an AC power source (or similar,
> such as a laptop powered by a 12V automotive adapter).
>
> PoDc (1) - The computer is powered by an onboard battery power source.
>
> PoHot (2) - The computer is powered by a short-term power source such
> as a UPS device.

Some code:

```
HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

HPOWERNOTIFY hPowerNotify;
hPowerNotify = RegisterPowerSettingNotification(hWnd, &GUID_ACDC_POWER_SOURCE, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);
...

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_POWERBROADCAST:
    {
            if (wParam == PBT_POWERSETTINGCHANGE) {
                POWERBROADCAST_SETTING* ppbs = (POWERBROADCAST_SETTING*)lParam;
                if (memcmp(&ppbs->PowerSetting, &GUID_ACDC_POWER_SOURCE, sizeof(GUID)) == 0) {
                    unsigned int power_state = *(unsigned int*)ppbs->Data;
                    if (power_state == 0 ) {
                        //The computer is powered by an AC power source (or similar, such as a laptop powered by a 12V automotive adapter).                            
                    }
                    else if(power_state == 1) {
                        //The computer is powered by an onboard battery power source.
                    }
                    eles if(power_state == 2) {
                     //The computer is powered by a short-term power source such as a UPS device.
                    }
                }
                return 0;
            }
    }
    break;
    ...
```